# sql case statement sql command not properly ended error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SQL> SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID,
  2  BOOKING.EVALUATIONRATING,
  3  EVENT.EVENTID
  4  FROM CUSTOMER
  5  INNER JOIN BOOKING
  6  ON BOOKING.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID
  7  INNER JOIN EVENT
  8  ON EVENT.EVENTID=BOOKING.EVENTID
  9  CASE EVALUATIONRATING
 10  WHEN 0 THEN 'TERRIBLE'
 11  WHEN 1 THEN 'BAD'
 12  WHEN 2 THEN 'MEDIOCRE'
 13  WHEN 3 THEN 'FAIR'
 14  ELSE 'GOOD';
CASE EVALUATIONRATING
*
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

I am getting an error when trying to add a case statement using a join. i want to convert number to text using a case construct.

Comment: I know of no reason why you CAN'T use a case statement in a join command, however in this case it looks like you are trying to get a field result. If that is the case, follow @SQLZim's answer below. If not, please describe more of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `case` should end with `end`, and be in the `select` portion of the query.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID,
  BOOKING.EVALUATIONRATING,
  EVENT.EVENTID,
  CASE EVALUATIONRATING
  WHEN 0 THEN 'TERRIBLE'
  WHEN 1 THEN 'BAD'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'MEDIOCRE'
  WHEN 3 THEN 'FAIR'
  ELSE 'GOOD'
  END CASE_EVALUATIONRATING
  FROM CUSTOMER
  INNER JOIN BOOKING
  ON BOOKING.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID
  INNER JOIN EVENT
  ON EVENT.EVENTID=BOOKING.EVENTID;
```